# scrollview lock in portrait orientation ios6

Tags: uiscrollview, ios6, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

I have to lock the scrollview in potrait orientation and not in landscape.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
        NSLog(@"inside the landscape rotation");
    }
    else
    {
        scrollview.scrollEnabled=NO;
        NSLog(@"inside the portrait rotation");
    }
}
```

The above method is working fine, but I have to rotate the device for once - is there any way to lock the scrollview in potrait without change the orientation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your your locking code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
    {
        scrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
        NSLog(@"inside the landscape roatation");
    }
    else
    {
        scrollview.scrollEnabled = NO;
        NSLog(@"inside the portrait roatation");
    }
}
```